# Sybase ASA database and listing columns with types

Tags: sql, sybase, sybase-asa

If i use in ASA Sybase database for getting columns:

```
select * from sys.syscolumns where table_id='1';
```

then i can get creator, table_name, column name, column type (varchar, int, ..) but no column id or table id cannot see.
How is the query, that i can get columns

```
creator, tname, cname, table_id, coltype, nulls, width, is_primary_key, default_value, remarks
```

I meaned, how to get the

```
select 
    t.creator, //i meaned schema name e.g public
    t.table_name, //the name of table e.g products
    t.table_id, //table's identifier
    c.column_name, //the name of  column, e.g price 
    c.column_type, //e.g varchar(255), integer, ..
    c.nulls, //not null or nulls
    c.width, //255 (varchar(255)), 4 (int(4))
    c.default //default value, the "default" is keyword and gives an error
  from sys.systab t, sys.systabcol c
where t.table_id = c.table_id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that sys.syscolumns is a view that is related to ASE compatibility.  You probably want to join SYSTAB, and SYSTABCOL.

```
select t.creator, t.table_name, t.table_id, c.column_type, c.nulls, c.width, c.default
  from sys.systab t, sys.systabcol c
where t.table_id = c.table_id
```

You may have to also reference SYSIDX to get the primary key information.

[References to the system tables and their structure can be found in the documentation](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.dbrfen10/pdf/dbrfen10.pdf).  In most cases you can use the SQLAnywhere v10 documentation to find answers about Sybase ASA.